# Using Python Selenium 4.13, still getting "your version of chrome not supported message"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniummanager

I just updated and verified that I am using Selenium 4.13. It's my understanding that Selenium Manager was being used with everything after Selenium 4.10 so I wouldn't have to worry about downloading the latest chromedriver every time a new Chrome version came out. I'm still in the learning stages with python so apparently I'm just not understanding something correctly.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. I'm importing selenium webdriver and the first thing i do is assign it to a variable, but it's coming back and telling me that my current browser version isn't being supported.  What am I not understanding? Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could happen if the built-in selenium manager doesn't have permission to delete the existing `chromedriver` so that it can download a newer one to that same location. You can use the following to ignore the mismatched versioning:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(service_args=["--disable-build-check"])
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
driver.quit()
```

At which point it should work, but you may start seeing a warning message such as:

`The chromedriver version (110.0.5481.77) detected in PATH at /usr/local/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (117.0.5938.92); currently, chromedriver 117.0.5938.92 is recommended for chrome 117.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry`

At which point you know exactly what to delete so that selenium manager downloads the newer version next time you run your script.

Comment: So does Selenium not actually save a version of the ChromeDriver? But just stores is it in memory or something? I used your trick above and deleted the chromedriver, and when I reran the RPA it ran but did not seem to install the latest chromedriver version.

Comment: There may be a bug with the built-in selenium manager, as it recently stopped downloading chromedriver automatically. Not long ago, people were using driver managers and frameworks such as `webdrivermanager` and `seleniumbase` to download drivers. Then selenium had a built-in driver manager... Then it stopped working recently. I'm using https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase for automatic driver management.

The `Service(service_args=["--disable-build-check"])` is a workaround for people who just want to keep raw selenium scripts working with existing drivers.